# Get reference to attributie inside html element

Tags: angular

**HTML**

```
<input #autoC auto-complete [(ngModel)]="myData" [source]="mySource" />
```

---

**TS**

```
@ViewChild('autoC') auto: ElementRef;
```

But when i use ViewChild I have reference to input and auto-complete is attributes. Is possible get reference to auto-complete. I need this element because i want change some css style in auto-complete? Using `[ngClass]` also add style to input element.

This is the [autocomplete package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngui/auto-complete)

Comment: if you want to change styles why not do this in the css / scss ? I mean find the class you want to change and change it if necessary use !important; on the attributes you want to change.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `@ViewChild('autoC') auto: HTMLElement;`. You'll get access to attributes and their get and set methods as well. Check below screenshot.

[image]